# Spring data elasticsearch - Aggregations in new version

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

We have been using spring-data-elasticsearch for 4.1.13 until recently for querying from elastic search. For grouping something we used aggregations
Consider a index of books. For each book there can be one or multipe authors
To get count of books by author we used TermsAggregationbuilder to get this grouping as shown below

```
SearchSourceBuilder builder = this.getQuery(filter, false);
String aggregationName = "group_by_author_id";

TermsAggregationBuilder aggregationBuilders =
    AggregationBuilders.terms(aggregationName).field("authors");

var query =
    new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(builder.query())
        .addAggregation(aggregationBuilders)
        .build();

var result = elasticsearchOperations.search(query, EsBook.class, ALIAS_COORDS);

if (!result.hasAggregations()) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("No aggregations found after query with aggregations!");
}
Terms groupById = result.getAggregations().get(aggregationName);
var buckets = groupById.getBuckets();

Map<Long, Integer> booksCount = new HashMap<>();
buckets.forEach(
    bucket ->
        booksCount.put(
            bucket.getKeyAsNumber().longValue(), Math.toIntExact(bucket.getDocCount())));

return booksCount ;
```

We recently upgraded to spring-data-elasticsearch 4.4.2 and saw that there are some breaking changes.
First .addAggregations were replaced by **withAggregations**

Second unlike before I cant seem to directly get Terms and buckets after querying as
**result.getAggregations().get(aggregationName);** is no more possible and only other option I see is **result.getAggregations().aggregations()**. So am wondering if anyone has done the same. The documentation itself is so poor in Elastic search.

Answer (score 1):

> First .addAggregations were replaced by withAggregations

`addAggregation(AbstractAggregationBuilder<?>)` has been deprecated and should be replaced by `withAggregations`. This is not a breaking change.

The change in the returned value for `SearchHits.getAggregations()` is [documented in the migration guides from 4.2 to 4.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.2-4.3.breaking-changes) "Removal of org.elasticsearch classes from the API."

So from 4.3 on `result.getAggregations().aggregations()` returns the same that previously `result.getAggregations()` returned.